# Change what happens onClick depending on which fragment is visible?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I have a layout with an image which should play a sound when clicked depending on which fragment is shown in the frame below the image.

All my fragments are in inner class.

I get a force close when I start the activity. Here's the issue...

This code is in all three of my fragments but with different sounds, sound1 for fragment, sound2 for fragment2 and so on....

```
public class Fragment_gehorINTbeginnerR8 extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)  {

        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }

        LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_musikteori_gehortest_int_beg, container, false);

        Button buttonR1 = (Button) mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.button_r1);
        Button buttonR5 = (Button) mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.button_r5);
        Button buttonR8 = (Button) mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.button_r8);


        ImageView imagePlay = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewPlayGehorSound);

        if(mp != null && mp.isPlaying()){
            mp.stop();

        }
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.inter_oktav);
        mp.start();

        imagePlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.stop();
                }
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.inter_prim);
                mp.start();
            }
        });



       some buttons....
```

Comment: Could you include the stack trace?

Comment: force close means there must be a stacktrace in logcat

Comment: Sorry, but where do I find the stack trace in Android Studio?

Comment: I don't use Android Studio, but there must be a logcat as well!

Comment: Ok, the error is in your `onCreateView` method, could you show me? especially this line: _Gehortestet_intervallerBeginner.java:292_

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48108/discussion-between-johgru-and-donfuxx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to every fragment:

```
public void playImageSound(){
            imagePlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
                        mp.stop();
                    }
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.soundx);
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
        }
```

And this in onCreate of every fragment:

```
fragmentx.playImageSound();
```